# Java 2 ME doesnt support replaceAll()

Tags: java, string, replace, java-me, replaceall

I am trying to use a method replaceAll in my Java 2 ME midlet, but recently found out, that there isn't such option. I was trying to recreate the method, but with no luck. Here is the code I tried:

```
public static String myReplaceAll(String str,String pattern,String replace ){
    int s =0;
    int e =0;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while((e = str.indexOf( pattern, s ))>=0){ 
        result.append(str.substring( s, e )); 
        result.append( replace ); 
        s = e+pattern.length();
    } 
    result.append( str.substring( s ));
        
    return result.toString();
}
```

When I try to run this code:

```
String pokus = "T+e+s+t č 1";
String test = myReplaceAll(pokus,"[^ A-Za-z0-9]","");
System.out.println(test);
```

It returns without changing. Is there a mistake in the code or does it not recognize "[^ A-Za-z0-9]" this part?

Comment: `indexOf()` doesn't use regular expressions so the pattern would be treated as a literal. You probably want to use `Pattern`, `Matcher` along with the matcher methods `appendReplacement(...)` and `appendTail(...)`. However, it seems Java ME doesn't support regular expressions out-of-the-box so you might need to use a library like https://code.google.com/archive/p/regexp-me/.

Comment: I've never used Pattern or Matcher before, I'll look into it and hopefully come up with something. Thanks for the quick response!